# Proxmox all containers are grey

Tags: containers, virtual-machine, proxmox

I've encountered an issue with my Proxmox VE setup where all Container containers are displayed as grey with question marks in the web interface, despite the node itself showing as green and healthy. This issue persists across different browsers and even in incognito mode. The containers are running correctly, and I can manage them via the command line without any issues.

Environment:

Proxmox VE version: 8.1.4
Single-node setup (no cluster configuration)
Affected services: containers display in the web interface
Steps Already Taken:

Checked the status of pveproxy and pvedaemon services; both are active and running.
Reviewed system logs (/var/log/syslog, /var/log/pveproxy/access.log, and other relevant logs) but found no significant errors related to this issue.
Confirmed that the issue is not related to browser cache by accessing the interface from different browsers and incognito mode.
Ran apt update && apt full-upgrade to ensure all packages are up to date.
Restarted Proxmox services (pvedaemon, pveproxy, etc.) multiple times. restarted the host it self
Verified VM and container statuses via command line (pct list for containers), which showed all as running normally.
Used pvesh get /nodes/proxmox/lxc/100/status/current to confirm the Proxmox API returns correct status information for containers.
Command Outputs for Reference:

Output of pct list (for all containers):
Bash:
root@proxmox:/etc/pve/nodes/proxmox/lxc# pct list
VMID       Status     Lock         Name
100        running                 GameServer
101        running                 NPM
102        running                 PostgreSQL
103        running                 Authentik
105        running                 NextCloud

Output of pvesh get /nodes/proxmox/lxc/100/status/current (example for one container):
Bash:
root@proxmox:/etc/pve/nodes/proxmox/lxc# pvesh get /nodes/proxmox/lxc/100/status/current
┌─────────┬───────────────┐
│ key     │ value         │
╞═════════╪═══════════════╡
│ cpus    │ 24            │
├─────────┼───────────────┤
│ ha      │ {"managed":0} │
├─────────┼───────────────┤
│ maxdisk │ 48.91 GiB     │
├─────────┼───────────────┤
│ maxmem  │ 64.00 GiB     │
├─────────┼───────────────┤
│ maxswap │ 4.00 GiB      │
├─────────┼───────────────┤
│ name    │ GameServer    │
├─────────┼───────────────┤
│ status  │ running       │
├─────────┼───────────────┤
│ uptime  │ 1h 52m 4s     │
├─────────┼───────────────┤
│ vmid    │ 100           │
└─────────┴───────────────┘